# Fast file listing incl sub folders

Tags: vb.net

What is the fastest way to retrieve all the files within a directory (including sub folders). Currently I am using this function:

```
    Public Function FindFiles(path As String, Recursive As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim dirInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(path)
    Dim fileObject As FileSystemInfo

    If Recursive = True Then
        For Each fileObject In dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()
            If System.IO.Directory.Exists(fileObject.FullName) Then
                FindFiles(fileObject.FullName, Recursive)
            Else
                'fileObject.FullName - found file
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For Each fileObject In dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()
            If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(fileObject.FullName) Then
                'fileObject.FullName - found file
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the need for the `Recursive` parameter? I think it could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Private Function getAllFolders(ByVal directory As String) As String()
    Dim fi As New IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)         'Create object
    Dim path() As String = {}                         'Array to store paths
    'Loop through subfolders
    For Each subfolder As IO.DirectoryInfo In fi.GetDirectories()
        Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)           'Add this folders name
        path(path.Length - 1) = subfolder.FullName
        'Recall function with each subdirectory
        For Each s As String In getAllFolders(subfolder.FullName)
            Array.Resize(path, path.Length + 1)
            path(path.Length - 1) = s
        Next
    Next
    Return path
End Function
```

Comment: johntotetwoo: That only lists folders. I am after files.